# QOpenGLContext get GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE always returns 0

Tags: c++, opengl, qt5

I want to obtain the value of `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE` in Qt "early" on as I will be generating some texture atlas for my app.

I understand that `glGetIntegerv` won't work without a "valid" context. So I create a `QOpenGLContext` and then call `glGetIntegerv` but this still returns 0, why?

```
QOpenGLContext c;
if ( !c.create() )
{
    abort();
}

int maxSize = 0;
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, &maxSize);

// maxSize == 0

auto err = glGetError();
// err == 0 too!
```

The target platform is Linux, running `glxinfo -l | grep MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE`  in a terminal returns

```
GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE = 16384
GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE = 16384
```

I should note that I have created a `QApplication` instance before `QOpenGLContext`, but this code is executed before the `QApplication` event loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of digging it appears that your context must be current, and this requires a surface. Since you probably don't want some random `QWindow` hanging around for this the Qt guys have added `QOffscreenSurface`:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtgui/qoffscreensurface.html

```
    // Create a temp context - required if this is called from another thread
    QOpenGLContext ctx;
    if ( !ctx.create() )
    {
        // TODO handle the error
    }

    // rather than using a QWindow - which actually dosen't seem to work in this case either!
    QOffscreenSurface surface;
    surface.setFormat( ctx.format() );
    surface.create();

    ctx.makeCurrent(&surface);

    // Now the call works
    int maxSize = 0;
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, &maxSize);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem that you did not activate OpenGL context.

Look on example:
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/openglwindow.html

try copy that example and check texture size after this line:

```
m_context->makeCurrent(this);
```

**UPDATE**:
checked [image]

Comment: I found using QGlContext rather than QOpenGLContext seemed to work.. seems like a hack to create another temp QGLContext though, why wouldn't it be active in the same place with a QOpenGLContext?

Comment: I'm not expert in Qt. I just on 100% precent sure that what I said above will work. About QGLContext and QOpenGLContext, there are 2 different classes for different situations, and looks like that QOpenGLContext will not work without QSurface, as described in documentation. But QGLContext could work.

Comment: Has QGLContext been deprecated by QOpenGLContext?

Comment: @paulm I've added screenshot with proof, it works :)

Comment: +1 so if I create a temporary window to make the context active it should then work no?

Comment: @paulm yes, I've used example "OpenGL Window Example" in Qt Creator

Comment: See my answer, looks like QOffscreenSurface is the thing to use, QWindow doesn't seem to work used in the same way, even though the QOffscreenSurface docs say it falls back to using this if not supported natively